# XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange not assigned

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

What happens if one uses XMLHttpRequest, in async mode, without assigning any function to XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange

Answer (score 0):

Expect it, nothing will happen as it is when you don't put 'document.onload = function(){};'.